# Copy MS-SQL table to local array

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Guys!

Can anyone tell me what is the best approach in VB.NET to get the entire table from the Ms SQL 2008 R2 database and save it in the program (dynamic?) array or something which is easy to translate into bytes and send to other device via socket communication?

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataSet to keep your Table and write that dataset to XML like bellow

```
Using Stream = New NetworkStream(socket)
    dataSet.WriteXml(Stream)
End Using
```